# How to get component name?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-template

How to get component name in Joomla 2.5 template?

ie: 
    `com_contact`, `com_search`, `com_kunena`?

I want to insert

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right"/>
```

only on kunena forum... How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php if(JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_kunena'): ?>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="right"/> 
<?php endif ?>
```

Instead of this just assign the module to the proper menu from the module manager then it will be available only on that pages.

Hope its helps..